# VSCode doesn't recognize CL even after being opened through Developer Command Prompt

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-code, cl

I'm trying to build C++ with VSCode using `cl`, and the [VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) (and most sources on the internet) instructs that the easiest way to do this is to just open VSCode through the Developer Command Prompt that ships with either Visual Studio or the Visual C++ Build Tools as such:

[image]

But then in VSCode's terminal:

[image]
`cl` is still not recognized. I'm not sure how to proceed, but it feels like I'm not doing something that I should.

Thanks in advance.

---

The tasks.json and c_cpp_properties.json file contents:

tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/Fe:",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "D:/Programas/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Looks like when running in powershell that cl is not in the path.

Comment: I expect you can fix this in your build problem in your `tasks.json` and `c_cpp_properties.json`

Comment: I added the files to the post. What do you suggest that could be done?

Comment: `"command": "cl.exe",` should probably have the full path to cl.exe like you have in the c_cpp_properties.json

Comment: whilst that fix the issue with recognizing `cl`, it's still missing path variable for include files like `iostream` and `vector`. And according to the docs linked in the post, I shouldn't have to do all that.

Answer (score 0):

The way I found to use the compilation tools was using "Visual Studio 2019 Developer Powershell". To do this, I wrote the following lines
(`"terminal.integrated.shell.windows"`, `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows"` and `"terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows"`):

```
{
        "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
        "editor.fontFamily": "CaskaydiaCove NF, Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
        "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "${env:USERPROFILE}\\.dotnet\\tools\\pwsh.exe",
        "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "-noe",
        "-c",
        "\"&{ $installDir='D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools'; Write-Host Using $installDir; Import-Module ($installDir + '\\Common7\\Tools\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll'); Enter-VsDevShell -VsInstallPath $installDir}; Set-Location '${workspaceFolder}' \""
    ],
        "terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": null,
}
```

or this way:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash"
        },
        "Developer PowerShell": {
            "path": [
                "${env:USERPROFILE}\\.dotnet\\tools\\pwsh.exe"
            ],
            "args": ["-noe",
                "-c",
                "\"&{ $installDir='D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools'; Write-Host Using $installDir; Import-Module ($installDir + '\\Common7\\Tools\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll'); Enter-VsDevShell -VsInstallPath $installDir}; Set-Location '${workspaceFolder}' \""
            ],
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
    },
```